# I suddenly received some downvotes, help me improve my questions.

Tags: discussion, down-votes

[image]

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451846/why-r-fracfn

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450899/left-a-n-a-1-a-n-a-2-text-a-n-a-m-text-right-varepsilon

[$\xi$ is the least upper bound of $M$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451725/xi-is-the-least-upper-bound-of-m)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450937/dedekinds-theorem-are-they-the-same

Why so many downvotes? my questions is too dummy? me dummy sorry.

How to avoid downvotes? I'm new here.

Comment: Some of those downvotes might have been consequence of [serial voting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/serial-voting/info), in which case they will be reversed.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I got -4k some days ago. Some of my students gave me more + without regarding the site policy. I am a loser. :(

Comment: @BabakS. Oh my.  Did you get +4339 for all the votes?  With a max of 200 a day, that would take weeks.  So, why would you lose them all at once?  Just to be clear, I'm asking, if you got 1000 upvotes by a few people in one day, you'd only get +200 rep.  Would you get -5000 when they were reversed?

Comment: @Graphth: Dear friend, I have not found out what exactly happened in days ago for me yet. The only thing I could get was that some of my students who were suggested to be here as users, made me + more than the legal level. This story was passed and I am OK with it. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Since the downvotes were all within minutes of each other, it is probably not due to your question. More likely, it is someone who dislikes something about you, and is serial downvoting you.

Answer (score 6):

You will notice that the downvotes have occurred within minutes of each other which means that someone is [serial voting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/serial-voting/info) or in this case, serial down voting. When this is the case, the system picks up on it and will correct it. If need more information check out: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)